# Javascript gets wrong charset when using .text with Japanese characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function that toggles the text of a button when clicked:

```
$(function() {
        $(".trigger-block").hide();
        $(".trigger").click(function() {
            $(this).parents(".more-cases").find(".trigger-block").slideToggle();
            $(this).toggleClass("close");
            $(this).text($(this).text() == "その他の事例を見る" ? "その他の事例を閉じる" : "その他の事例を見る");
        });
    });
```

It works with English but it outputs squares with questions marks if I use Japanese.
I have charset=UTF-8 inside  and also put it on the script tag with no success.

```
<script src="js/page.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Can some guide me to the solution? I've searched on various Japanese forums and haven't found an answer. I've had success using Japanese with .append so I don't know what is causing this problem.

EDIT: .append works on a different js file but not this one. I'm still trying to figure out what is different between those files.

Comment: So you're confident the js file is encoded as UTF-8? You can test that by doing `await fetch("js/page.js").then(resp => resp.text()).then(txt => txt.includes("その他の事例を見る"));` in your console from that page. However if it wasn't `append` shouldn't work... So maybe your Document isn't configured correctly. What does `document.characterSet` output?

Comment: @Kaiido I'll edit the question because .append stopped working also! It only happens with the page.js file though. `document.characterSet` returns UTF-8 while await fetch returns false.

Comment: So it's indeed your js file's encoding. If it was properly encoded as UTF-8 Response.text() would have been able to decode it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the original file I was editing was not encoded properly. I've reached a solution by simply making a new .js file, and copying the original code to it. Thank you all for the support!